# Cannot set more than 1 cookie in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, httpcookie, discourse

I am making some changes in discourse platform. at a point i want to set 2 cookies namely
sso_payload & sso_destination_url

here is what i am doing

```
cookies[:sso_payload] = payload || request.query_string
cookies[:sso_destination_url] = data[:return_sso_url]
```

however when i open application tab in google dev tools, only sso_payload cookie is set. I am new to ruby on rails please help

Comment: perhaps `data[:return_sso_url]` is nil or empty ...

Comment: @LamPhan it isnt empty or nil i have verified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store these multiple cookies in an cookie-array, like below:

```rb
cookies[:cookies_array] = [payload || request.query_string, data[:return_sso_url]]
```

The downside is that you need to parse when reading.

Comment: isnt there any other way of storing multiple cookies. because other frameworks like node express php provides that